# Update one array based on another array

Tags: ruby, arrays, object

Let's say I have

```
a = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g"]
b = a.map(&:upcase)
a.delete("a")

print b # right now b = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G"]
        # I want    b = ["B","C","D","E","F","G"]
```

I want `b` to dynamically update itself based on what `a` has so that, in the end, `b` prints out without `"a"` because `"a"` was removed from `a`. I want `b` to be a separate object from `a`; I do not want to modify `a` in place (no `map!`). Is this possible?

Comment: Just using `a.map(&:upcase)` shouldn't modify in place.

Comment: @Undo The OP wants a *dependent* array that shares members, but displays the array members differently. Same contents, but different behavior. It's likely an X/Y problem, but it's certainly doable with minimal ceremony using Proc or lambda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### TL;DR

You appear to want a dependent array that shares members with another array, but displays the array members differently. You can do this with a Ruby [closure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_programming%29).

### Create a Closure with a "Stabby" Lambda

There's more than one way to provide multiple representations of a single data set with varying behavior. However, defining a custom class might be overkill for your use case. I think assigning a [lambda](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Kernel.html#method-i-lambda) to *b* is the easiest way to accomplish what you want, at least in the sense of treating *a* and *b* as separate-but-connected objects. Consider:

```
a = %w[a b c d e f g]
b = ->{ a.map(&:upcase) }
a.delete ?a

b.call
#=> ["B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"]

a
#=> ["b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"]
```

Comment: This is very interesting and suits my purposes quite well. Thank you very much. I have to say, the Proc class is very cool.